# Recognize file format and open it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Python script that does lot of transformation on a dataframe. The source is a csv file.

`df = pd.read_csv(r'input.csv', sep=';', header=0)`

I have to do the same transformations but with an excel file as an input. I want my script to recognize if the input is a csv or an excel and open it the same way as if I did
`pd.read_excel('input.xls')`

Comment: Will be your excel file always `.xls` or might it be also `.xlsx`?

Comment: Use an [`if` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements). This can also be done with [`try`/`except`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions).

Comment: @Daweo it might be both, is it possible? Because I know read_excel supports only .xls files.

Comment: @Awans [pandas.read_excel docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) states that *Supports xls, xlsx, xlsm, xlsb, odf, ods and odt file extensions read from a local filesystem or URL.*

Answer (score 0):

You can first check the file extension of the file passed and open it properly
Thhi can be one way to do it

```py
import os
import pandas as pd

# your file with the extension of choice e.g .csv 
input_file = 'data_file.csv'

filename, file_ext = os.path.splitext(input_file)

df = None

if file_ext == '.csv':
   df = pd.read_csv(input_file, sep=';', header=0)

if file_ext == '.xls':
   df = pd.read_excel(input_file)
```